# Adding Search functions to a Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, button

Currently I'm working on a movie search I have included a screenshot of it.

As you can see in the clip there is a button next to each result.

I want to assign that value to that button so i can rerun a new search using that title and not the original search one.

From my own reasearch i think i need to change from a each statement to a for loop maybe but that is just a guess.

Would love any help u could provide jsfiddle examples would be loved

Screenshot Below,
[image]

I have also include all of my code so far.

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Sample Seach</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
    mode = 'search/movie',
    input,
    movieName,
    key = '?api_key='API KEY';

    $('#search').click(function() {
        var input = $('#movie').val(),
            movieName = encodeURI(input);
        $.ajax({
            url: url + mode + key + '&query='+movieName ,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {

        var table = '<table>';
        $.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {
          table += '<tr><td class="results-img"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + value.poster_path +'" alt="" width="150" height="200"></td><td class="results-title">' + value.original_title + '</td><td class="results-date">' + value.release_date + 
          '</td><td class="results-search-btn"><button class="search-btn" id="MoreInfo">Few More Info</button></td></tr>';
        });
        $('#searchresult').html(table);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
<script text="text/javascript">
// When the more button is click this runs a search using the title of the movie 
$(document).on('click', '.search-btn', function() {
    getImdbInfo( $(this).closest('td').prev('.results-title').text() );
});

//The function below takes the entered title and searchs imdb for a match then it displays as followed

function getImdbInfo(Title) {
    var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + Title;
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data) {

            var str = "";
            str += "<h2>Title :" +data.Title+ "</h2>";
            str += "<p>Year :" +data.Plot+ "</p>";

            $("#chosenresult").html(str);
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) { alert(status + ", " + error); }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Movie Search</h1>
<input id="movie" type="text" /><button id="search">Search</button>
</center>
<div id="searchresult"></div>
<div id="chosenresult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The most relevant things to show in this question are the HTML returned from the ajax call and what you're doing with it via jQuery. The ajax code is irrelevant, unless I'm missing something. Please show an example of the search results HTML.

Comment: I have include a screen shot of the search results and this is all of my code. Just in case im not being clear i want to link the search result title to the More info button beside it as u can see in the scren shot

Comment: You're clear, but I'm still requesting the HTML that appears in the browser. I realize that it's not in your source code, but that's what your jQuery will act on, so it's helpful to see its structure.

Comment: this is all of my code the only thing not there is myapi key

Comment: You're still not getting me. Use a document inspector (F12) and examine the rendered HTML in your page. Copy the relevant bits and post them.

Comment: i have run it and pasted the above html from the brower

Comment: No. The HTML I'm asking for should have an image, the movie title, the movie date, and a button labelled "Few More Info".

Comment: add the code u want above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this HTML

```
<tr>
    <td><img src="http://... .jpg" alt="" width="150" height="200"></td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>2006-12-08</td>
    <td><button id="MoreInfo">Few More Info</button></td>
</tr>
```

...you should be able to use DOM traversal to grab the title for your search like so:

```
$(document).on('click', 'td button', function() {
    getImdbInfo( $(this).closest('tr').('td').eq(2).text() );
});
```

However, I get the impression that you have the same ID value on each of those buttons, which is invalid. You should work some classes into your structure and target those instead, like so:

```
<tr>
    <td class="results-img"><img src="http://... .jpg" alt="" width="150" height="200"></td>
    <td class="results-title">300</td>
    <td class="results-date">2006-12-08</td>
    <td class="results-search-btn"><button class="search-btn" id="MoreInfo_1">Few More Info</button></td>
</tr>
```

...

```
$(document).on('click', '.search-btn', function() {
    getImdbInfo( $(this).closest('td').prev('.results-title').text() );
});
```